# Which is faster: Using bootstrap CDN or downloaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a single page website:

- index.html
- /css

  - /css/style.css
- /js

  - /js/main.js

Will my website load quicker when using the Bootstrap CDN (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/) or to download the compressed .js and .css files (i.e. bootstrap.min.css & bootstrap.bundle.min.js?

- index.html
- /css

  - /css/bootstrap.min.css
  - /css/style.css
- /js

  - /js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
  - /js/main.js

I am also wondering the same question for jQuery.

Comment: CDN might already be cached, depending where the user has visited recently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In theory, there should be no difference, once the library is loaded. So that is the determining factor. In the end, it all comes down to the Client and not really the hosted location. Assuming your Website is hosted on a fast server, it should be just as fast as a CDN. The only benefit to a CDN is they may be able to Cache the content and make it a bit more readily available.

Comment: To improve the "speed" of your website, meaning how quickly it is transferred to the Client, you can Minimize your libraries and reduce them to just using the code you are absolutely needing. I don't use Bootstrap, but if you can roll your own, pick and choose the elements in the framework that you need, then you can reduce the amount of data to transfer and thus improve the "speed".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is depends on:

1. Can you serve the bootstrap faster than a CDN? Is your server closer to your client then bootstrap CDN closest server?
2. Are you using full bootstrap features? If not you can build a smaller css and js bundle with just features that you need.
3. Do your client accesses any site that uses bootstrap? (Hard to guess, but with some sort of analysis you can get a number)

Usually it's a good idea to use the CDN since it will be close enough to most of the places world-wide, but not everytime you have a world-wide website. So, it depends!

Comment: If the folder of your Bootstrap is changed for some reason by someone to have separate folder mentality, then your are screwed. You have to change the path everything time which can be ridiculous. :D